# How to disable 8080 external access to jenkins?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed nginx along with jenkins on ubuntu 21 machine.

Configured nginx to redirect 80 traffic to 8080 using the steps in this [link](https://esc.sh/blog/jenkins-nginx-ssl/)

Now, able to redirect the traffic from 80 to 8080.
So, to disable direct access to jenkins from 8080 externally.
Changed the arguments in /etc/default/jenkins to add line --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1

Now, the jenkins arguments line is as below.

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"
```

Then, restarted the machine also after that but still able to access directly with 8080 port.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

```
azureuser@jenkins:~$ ss -lnpt
State         Recv-Q        Send-Q               Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port       Process
LISTEN        0             511                        0.0.0.0:80                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                 127.0.0.53%lo:53                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             128                        0.0.0.0:22                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                             *:3000                          *:*
LISTEN        0             50                               *:8080                          *:*
LISTEN        0             128                           [::]:22                         [::]:*

azureuser@jenkins:~$ ps auxw | grep jenkins
jenkins     6761  0.1 11.8 3036280 416756 ?      Ssl  Mar29   8:08 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
azureus+   86025  0.0  0.0   8548  2356 pts/0    S+   19:09   0:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

Comment: Please add output of `ss -lnpt` to the question.

Comment: added, can you check

Comment: It seems that the Jenkins doesn't apply the configuration correctly for some reason, since the binding is still to `*:8080` in the listing. What is output of `ps auxw | grep jenkins`?

Comment: Added the output, can you check now

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins command line does not include the option set in `/etc/default/jenkins` for some reason.

Please double-check that the `JENKINS_ARGS` is correct and includes the option. Try also to restart Jenkins.

Comment: I am using the default one only. Only difference I did is adding the paramertes --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, and as shown in the process listing, the arguments are not passed to Jenkins.

Comment: I have just gone through the default steps of jenkins installation. I didn't tamper anything. As you stated, if it is missing here then it is missing with jenkins debian/ubuntu installation itself. So, please suggest what is missing and what to add then.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71533015/12385916) answer, `/etc/default/jenkins` file is no longer used in recent Jenkins versions. You will need to update the Jenkins systemd service to achieve your goal:

1. Open `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` via text editor.
2. Locate the line containing Jenkins listening address environment variable: `#Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS="`
3. Remove the comment and update the variable value with the local IP: `Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1"`
4. Save the file and reload systemd unit files: `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Restart Jenkins: `systemctl restart jenkins`

Jenkins sould be listening on localhost now:

```
$ netstat -plunt | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      11661/java
```